# Opening a view from a custom class Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have this problem:

Im having a custom class named `CoredataAction`

In this class I do all my CoreData actions and it is not an `UIViewController`.

How can I open a view from my `CoreDataAction` class?

I have tryied opening a storyboard but did didn't work! It got me an bad_access error

Comment: What do you mean by "open a view from my `CoreDataAction` class"?

Comment: present a view controller. So load a new view depending on the outcome of the result.

Comment: Did you call your `CoredataAction` class from an initial ViewController?

Comment: Yes only there is some flow control present so its not the first method

Comment: @Twizzler usually, you have instantiated `CoreDataAction` somewhere, this could be inside a `UIViewController` which controls the instance wrt (user) actions. So you would create views or content from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to add a variable in your `CoredataAction` class that holds the initial `ViewController`, just make sure you set that variable when you initialise your `CoredataAction` class.

**CoredataAction**

```
class CoredataAction {
    var parentViewController:UIViewController!

    func presentNewViewController() {
        let newViewController = parentViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR STORYBOARD ID") as UIViewController
        parentViewController.presentViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func initCustomClass() {
    var coreData = CoredataAction()
    coreData.parentViewController = self
}
```

Another option is to use a protocol to delegate the view presentation back to the `ViewController` class itself. It would be a very similar setup to the above, it just means the view presentation logic can be kept out of your `CoredataAction` customClass - Let me know if you would like an example of this.